# Retrofit URL with headers and params

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am having some troubles with Retrofit 2 library. I want to send headers and parameters with https request, I have the following url from log:

https://api.trakt.tv/movies/popular(page='1')?limit=10&extended=full,images

I got 404 status code. The above Url is correct?

String ENDPOINT = "https://api.trakt.tv/";

```
@GET("movies/popular(page='{page}')?limit=10&extended=full,images")
public Observable<PopularMoviesResponse> getPopularMovies(@Header("trakt-api-version") String trakt_api_version,
                                                  @Header("trakt-api-key") String trakt_api_key,
                                                  @Path("page") String page);

/********
 * Helper class that sets up a new services
 *******/
class Creator {

    public static MovieService newSurveiesService() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
                .create();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(MovieService.ENDPOINT)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();


        return retrofit.create(MovieService.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try going there from a browser?

Comment: I am using PostMan because I am sending headers data. I have just tested it with it after your comment and it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to GET it? Does it work in Postman?

Comment: I am using GET. It didn't work with Postman. Anyway, the format is correct in the above url?

Comment: It doesn't look like it. I think it should be  https://api.trakt.tv/movies/popular?page=1&limit=10&extended=full,images check out the documentation here: http://docs.trakt.apiary.io/#introduction/pagination

Comment: Yes. I know. But I am using Retrofit 2 library with annotations, the posted url is the url that come in log while executing the request. Your url works fine,

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: @Bryan I have updated my post.

Comment: BTW,
I have tried to edit the above url and testes it with postman with the required headers and it works:
https://api.trakt.tv/movies/popular?(page='1')&limit=10&extended=full,images

But I have tried to edit my code and place the ? but logs tell me I need to use @Query to do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your url in `@GET` is wrong, based on the fact that you said the url @CaseyB provided works.

```
@Get("movies/popular?page={page}&limit=10&extended=full,images")
```

Alternatively, you could use the `@Query` annotation to  have `Retrofit` to take care of the query string for you:

```
@Get("movies/popular")
public Observable<PopularMoviesResponse> getPopularMovies(
                                              @Header("trakt-api-version") String trakt_api_version,
                                              @Header("trakt-api-key") String trakt_api_key,
                                              @Query("page") int page,
                                              @Query("limit") int limit,
                                              @Query("extended") String extended);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have just found the solution before a couple of mins!!